# jquery show() functions loads user view to top of page

Tags: jquery

I have a job site where initially only job titles and business addresses are shown and when a user clicks a job title the details of the job are shown, when the user clicks another job the first job details are hidden and the second are shown. This is done with:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".job_link").click(function(){
            $(".job_description").hide();
            $(this).parents('.job').find(".job_description").show();
        });
    });
```

But when a user clicks a job title the view is always reloaded to the top of the screen. How can I focus the view on the job title they clicked on?
https://jsfiddle.net/j60y9h3v/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is make sure you're preventing the default behavior of that anchor tag. The default behavior will try and reload to another page. Try passing in the event and then passing it e.preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".job_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".job_description").hide();
        $(this).parents('.job').find(".job_description").show();
    });
});
```